# How to use Material Design Icons In Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to use the icons from https://materialdesignicons.com/ in my angular 4 project. 
The instructions on the website are only covering how to include it in `Angular 1.x` (https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started)

How can I include the Material design icons so I can use them like `<md-icon svgIcon="source"></md-icon>` using `Angular Material` and `ng serve`?

**NOTE: I already Included the `google material icons` which are different!**

Comment: Extended icons are supported [here](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/icons). Follow the instructions given in the answer above by **Edric**. The latest path for getting the **mdi.svg** is [here](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/angular#angular-material).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instructions on how to include Material Design Icons into your Angular Material app can now be found on the [Material Design Icons - Angular](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/angular#angular-material) documentation page.

TL;DR: You can now leverage the [`@mdi/angular-material`](https://npmjs.com/package/@mdi/angular-material) NPM package which includes the MDI icons distributed as a single SVG file (`mdi.svg`):

```sh
npm install @mdi/angular-material
```

This SVG file can then be included into your app by including it in your project's `assets` configuration property in `angular.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": [
          { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/", "output": "./assets/" },
          { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "./", "output": "./" },
          { "glob": "mdi.svg", "input": "./node_modules/@mdi/angular-material", "output": "./assets" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Your app's main module will also need the necessary imports (`HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` used to load the icons and `MatIconModule` from `@angular/material/icon`) to be declared, as well as adding the icon set to the registry:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
      domSanitizer.bypassSecurityResourceHtml('./assets/mdi.svg')
    );
  }
}
```

A [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mdi-material-example) is also now available.

The steps for older versions of Angular are as mentioned below:

---

Simply follow these steps:

1. Download `mdi.svg` from [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started) under the **Angular Material** section and place it in your `assets` folder, which should be located at (from your project's root) `/src/assets`:

   [image: Documentation]
   [image: assets folder]
2. In your app's module (aka `app.module.ts`), add the following lines:

   ```ts
   import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
   import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   ...
   export class AppModule {
     constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){
       matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(domSanitizer.bypassSecurityResourceUrl('/assets/mdi.svg'));
     }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure to include `assets` folder under `.angular-cli.json` in `assets` (Although by default, it will be there):

   ```json
   {
     "apps": [
       {
         ...
         "assets": [
           "assets"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Finally, use it via the `MatIcon` component with the `svgIcon` input:

   ```html
   <mat-icon svgIcon="open-in-new"></mat-icon>
   ```

Comment: Thanks you very much :D

Comment: Thank you for your informative response.I have been battling a very bizarre issue over the past day. I am using <md-icon svgIcon="PATH"></md-icon> successfully on my local environment. Icons show up and everything is beautiful
when I deploy the same code to my test server I get the following error. Error retrieving icon: <svg> tag not found
basically the <svg> tag does not get rendered inside md-icon. I can confirm that all SVGs return 200 and are loaded correctly. There are no other issues whatsoever. I would appreciate any help or hint. I am keeping my SVG folder under my public folder

Comment: @RiceJunkie What version of angular-material2 are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.3.6. I can confirm that it has nothing to do with the build tool and the file assets are included in the build. I ended up using HTML5 SVG tags but it would be nice to know why it didn't work.

Comment: bypassSecurityResourceUrl doesn't exist on domSanitizer. also it's not MdIconRegistry it's MatIconRegistry. and you need to add the npm install part. your guide needs to be updated.

Comment: MatIconModule    *

Comment: @tatsu What `npm install`? I've updated the md prefix to mat.

Comment: npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

Comment: as far as I understand without them it can't work? or can it?

Comment: @tatsu I'm expecting those who read this guide already know how to setup Angular and Angular Material, but feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: the thing is I disagree with Material's distribution of it's npm packages. both these packages are served straight from github and as such fail to download within big businesses (which have company firewalls). Do you know of an npm mirror for these?

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the font instead of SVG? It's a lot smaller.

Answer (score 83):

For those who prefer to use SCSS:

Install the font

```sh
$> npm install material-design-icons
```

import in `src/styles.scss`

```css
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

and use it in HTML as described [here](https://material.io/icons/#ic_visibility)

```html
<!-- write the desired icon as text-node -->
<i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
```

In Order to refer to [Sam Claus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5054792/sam-claus) comment, thank you for this, I've added the installation and use of Templarian's design icons. It is similar to the one above.

Install the font through the package manager

```sh
$> npm install @mdi/font
```

import the stylesheet in `src/styles.scss`, or in `angular.json` as described in the comment of [A. Morel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736742/a-morel) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677960/how-to-use-material-design-icons-in-angular-4/53575087#53575087)

```css
@import '~@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
```

or using the [CDN URL](https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.7.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css) in index.html or wherever
and use it in HTML as described [here](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/webfont)

```html
<!-- use the symbol name as a class instead of a text-node -->
<span class="mdi mdi-home"></span>
```

**Addendum**: My answer's a little bit older. This still works fine but is no longer state of the art. The answer of [A. Morel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736742/a-morel) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677960/how-to-use-material-design-icons-in-angular-4/53575087#53575087) is a bit more contemporary.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: this answer misses the steps where you have to add the path to the css file in `angular.json`and restart the server (ng serve`) as detailed in @A.Morel answer below. And also the steps for àpp.module.ts` .

Comment: The question was asking about Material Design Icons by Templarian, NOT the ones provided by Google (material-design-icons on NPM).

Answer (score 23):

Install npm package

```
npm install material-design-icons --save
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Add material icons css to your .angular-cli.json (don't forget to restart "ng serve")

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

or in your src/styles.scss

```
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

Import module in your app.module.ts

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

...

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ...,
      MatIconModule
  ],
```

And use it like that:

```
<mat-icon>location_off</mat-icon>
```

Pick the name from Material Design Icons => https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: but it's unfortunate that you have to install the entire material dependency just to use the ´<mat-icon` tags and icons. That's what it means, right ?

Comment: @bvdb The latest versions of Angular do a lot of tree shaking and compile-time magic. I still don't fully understand to be honest, but when you build for production with ahead-of-time compilation, new Angular will literally compile your templates to TypeScript code and transpile that to JavaScript. You also only pay for modules you use from libraries. It will not bundle all of Angular Material if you just use the icons module.

Answer (score 17):

Similar to the answer by @creep3007, you can specify the stylesheet in your `.angular-cli.json`:

1. Install npm package

   ```
   npm install material-design-icons --save
   ```
2. Add material icons to your .angular-cli.json

   ```
   {
     "apps": [
       {
         "styles": [
           "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Use it

   ```
   <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
   ```

Comment: OP doesn't use Google Material Design Icons. He uses MaterialDesignIcons by Templarian.

Comment: which is the best way to include material icon, include it into scss file or into angular-cli.json ?

Answer (score 9):

**Note** this answer applies to the [Material Design Icons by Templarian](https://materialdesignicons.com/) and NOT the icons of the same name by Google. I don't understand why these instructions aren't in the Readme, but here you go.

First, install the package:

`npm install @mdi/font --save`

Then, it is necessary to add the stylesheet to your `styles.scss` file. I added the following to the end of my file:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Material Design Icons (https://materialdesignicons.com/)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$mdi-font-path: "~@mdi/font/fonts";
@import "~@mdi/font/scss/materialdesignicons.scss";
```

**Note** the `$mdi-font-path` is necessary to override a default set within the `@mdi/font/scss/_variables.scss` which causes the webpack compiler to complain. If you forget to do this, you will get a series of errors, as follows:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--3-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles.scss
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot' in
>   '/home/myRepo/myApp'

**Edit**: I'm not sure if this is necessary (it probably is in some cases), but I also updated the `.angular-cli.json` file `styles` element:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/@mdi/icon/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
```

---

Another alternative to the above, which resulted in the icons working with very little effort, was to import the CSS directly. In the typescript file, I replaced the `styleUrls` element (to avoid a strange bug with Karma):

```
 // styleUrls: ['./graphics-control.component.css'],
  styles: [require('./my.component.css'),
           require('../pathTo/node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css')]
```

Answer (score 4):

With Bootstrap 4 & Angular this works:

1) Run:

```
npm install material-design-icons --save
```

2) Add to styles.css or styles.scss

`@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';`

3) Go to: **..\node_modules\material-design-icons\iconfont\material-icons.css** and make sure the section is exactly like this ('MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2')...:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url('MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('MaterialIcons-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

4) Use icon in html:

```
<i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
```

Answer (score 4):

Base on **@theMayer** answer, there is my version to make it work for package `@mdi/font`.

1- `npm install @mdi/font --save`

2- In `angular.json`, under `architect/buid/options/styles`, add `"node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"`

3- In `src\app\app.module.ts` add `import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';` and add `MatIconModule` in `imports` section

4- In `src\styles.scss` add:

```
$mdi-font-path: "~@mdi/font/fonts";
@import "~@mdi/font/scss/materialdesignicons.scss";
```

5- Add the icon in your html using mat-icon, for example:

```
<mat-icon class="mdi mdi-dumbbell" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install icons using this command - 
   `npm install material-design-icons --save`
2. Then add this line in the styles array - `"./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"`

Answer (score 0):

1. installlibraries -

npm i --save @angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/animations hammerjs

2. add the below import in styles.css

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";

3. inside app.module.ts -

3.1 import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

3.2 add  MatIcomModule   in imports array

4. then in your app.component.html

   ## icons:

   home
   add_alert

Answer (score 0):

I created the `ngx-md-icon` component, that allows easy usage of the `@mdi/js` modules. This benefits from tree shaking, no extra static assets and minimal overhead.
https://github.com/btxtiger/ngx-md-icon

```
// Single icon
<md-icon [icon]="icons.industryVehicle"></md-icon>

// Stack multiple icons
<md-icon [icons]="[icons.industryVehicle, icons.strike]"></md-icon>
```